# PHP - Requirements to change Return-Path in email

Tags: php, email

I need to send emails through mail().

Do I need a root server to change the `Return-Path` value?
Currently it's `www-data@mydomainname.com` but I'd like to have it the same address like `From` and `Reply-to`.

I set the `Return-Path` like below but it stays `www-data@mydomainname.com`:

```
$headers.="Return-Path: $from\r\n";
```

Thank you.

Comment: If i were you i would jsut use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer the provide a consistenet API for this thats well tested and you in the case of Swift you can easily switch between transports (`mail`, `smtp`, etc.).

Comment: Your question depends. Contact your hoster and ask how this is done with their server, you normally do not need a root-server for that. Sometimes it's the fith parameter, sometimes it's an ini-setting, sometimes it's the header and sometimes you need to change that in a webinterface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also set the fifth parameter of mail function to adjust the return path

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f email@wherever.com");
```